# Automated app-deployment on cloud server

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-server, git, automation

I've been hosting my applications at `AWS EC2` and one of these days I tried `OpenShift`, what I liked of it was that the whole deployment process is automated, but I disliked the pricing since I know that using EC2 is cheaper because I can host many apps in a same server.

I want to know how could I mimic OpenShift process for my own deployments at AWS?, the reason is obvious, the process is repetitive, every time I want to add an application I have to create a new virtual host and point to run *node.js/php/python*... Also another feature that I liked of OS was that I didn't need to upload the whole project, in fact, I just had to push the `git` repo in order to deploy it.

Thanks to @BillSchaller I found that AWS platform offer things to get this done, the thing is that it's confusing since there are many services like `CodeCommit, CodeDeploy, CodePipeline, OpsWork` that seems to do similar things... Do they complement each other or what?

So here's the thing:

1. What AWS Product/s suits to setup an infrastructure to be able to do the following:

   - Create Application Instances that generates git repositories and virtual hosts configurations that will work with either node.js/php/python/java
   - Update the production application when git repo is pushed(updated), and if possible having two states to handle the dev and production
   - Setup SSL certificates per app
2. Which of the AWS products suits better in this case based on:

   - I want to decide which git hosting to use(basically I'll use Upsource, if not Bitbucket, last option Github cause of pricing)
   - If possible I want a GUI for the process
   - I like to have three EC2 instances (node.js, php/python, java) and a RDS database

NOTE: I don't want to create a server per app, I want to host many apps in same server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS OpsWorks to do this. You can simply have a webhook set up in github for example, and have it push to a script that fires an OpsWorks deploy event via the AWS CLI.

Comment: Let's take this to a chat at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97991/aws

Comment: I updated the questions dude

Comment: Here's a pretty good writeup of how to integrate CodeDeploy with OpsWorks - You can push multiple apps to one stack this way. http://hipsterdevblog.com/blog/2014/11/23/integrating-opsworks-and-codedeploy/